# Finding a point exactly between two points on a map at a specific distance from one point

Tags: javascript, google-maps, deployment, google-maps-api-3

I've been working on a mapping project and encountered a problem where I need to find a point exactly between two given points on a map, at a specific distance from one of the points. I've tried various approaches, but haven't been able to achieve the desired result.

I've researched and found a formula to calculate the distance between two points on the Earth's surface, and I've adjusted it accordingly. Now, I'm trying to use this formula to find a third point on the map that lies exactly between the two given points and is at a specific distance from one of them.

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
// Variable declare
let start_get_lat = 31.5387761;
let start_get_lng = 72.9696664;
let end_get_lat = 31.569235;
let end_get_lng = 72.983557;
let center = {lat: Number(start_get_lat), lng: Number(start_get_lng)};
let endLocation = {lat: Number(end_get_lat), lng: Number(end_get_lng)};
```

Calculate distance bw two points and

```
// calculate distance function 
const distance = calculateDistance(lat1, lon1, centerLat, centerLon);
```

Get point bwtween function and usage

```
function getPointBetween(startLat, startLng, endLat, endLng, distance) {
    const earthRadius = 6371000; // Earth's radius in meters

    // Convert latitudes and longitudes from degrees to radians
    const lat1 = startLat * Math.PI / 180;
    const lon1 = startLng * Math.PI / 180;
    const lat2 = endLat * Math.PI / 180;
    const lon2 = endLng * Math.PI / 180;

    // Calculate the angular distance between the points
    const delta = distance / earthRadius;

    // Calculate the intermediate point
    const A = Math.sin((1 - delta) * Math.PI / 2) + Math.sin(delta * Math.PI / 2) * Math.cos(lat1) * Math.cos(lat2);
    const B = Math.sin(delta * Math.PI / 2) * Math.sin(lon2 - lon1) * Math.cos(lat2);
    const C = Math.atan2(B, A);
    const lat3 = Math.asin(A * Math.sin(lat1) + B * Math.sin(lat2)) * 180 / Math.PI;
    const lon3 = (lon1 + Math.atan2(Math.sin(lon2 - lon1) * Math.cos(lat2), Math.cos(lat1) * Math.sin(lat2) + Math.sin(lat1) * Math.cos(lat2) * Math.cos(lon2 - lon1))) * 180 / Math.PI;

    return { lat: lat3, lng: lon3 };
}

let anyDistance = distance - 1000;
const pointBetween = getPointBetween(start_get_lat, start_get_lng, end_get_lat, end_get_lng, anyDistance);
let bwMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: pointBetween,
    map: map,
    title: "Center",
    fillColor: 'blue', //
});
console.log(pointBetween);
```

However, while this function returns a point between the two coordinates, it does not guarantee that the point lies exactly on the line segment between them at the specified distance. The goal is to achieve a precise displacement from one of the given points.

I'm looking for insights or alternative manual calculation methods to achieve this precise displacement between two coordinates without using google map, as I need a solution that can be implemented in both front-end and back-end environments.

Any suggestions or advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time and assistance!

Comment: If you are using the Google Maps Javascript API v3, why aren't you using the [geometry library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry)?

Comment: [proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/3akqevdo/)

Comment: basically i need to run function every second may be 10 time in a second in a laravel at backend so i am avoiding  using google map. Basically acording to project i am handling it from backend

Comment: https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution for Propagating Point on Google Maps

After some experimentation, I've found a simple and effective solution for propagating a point on Google Maps towards another point. Here's the JavaScript function I came up with:

```js
function propagatePoint(latlng1, latlng2, distanceToPropagate, totalDistanceBwPoints) {
    let ratio = distanceToPropagate / totalDistanceBwPoints;
    let newLat = latlng1[0] + (latlng2[0] - latlng1[0]) * ratio;
    let newLng = latlng1[1] + (latlng2[1] - latlng1[1]) * ratio;
    return { lat: newLat, lng: newLng };
}
```

I've also improved the precision of the formula to enhance accuracy:

```js
const totalDistanceBwPoints = calculateDistance(latlng1[0], latlng1[1], latlng2[0], latlng2[1]);

function calculateDistance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2) {
    const earthRadius = 6371; // Radius of the Earth in kilometers
    const dLat = toRadians(lat2 - lat1);
    const dLon = toRadians(lon2 - lon1);
    const a = Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2) +
        Math.cos(toRadians(lat1)) * Math.cos(toRadians(lat2)) *
        Math.sin(dLon / 2) * Math.sin(dLon / 2);
    const c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
    const distance = earthRadius * c; // Distance in kilometers

    // Calculate the percentage
    const percentage = (distance * 0.11202322513989) / 100; // 0.1121% precision percentage

    // Add the percentage to the distance
    const distanceWithPercentage = distance + percentage;

    return (distanceWithPercentage * 1000).toFixed(4);
}
```

This function takes the latitude and longitude coordinates of two points (`latlng1` and `latlng2`), along with the distance to propagate `distanceToPropagate` and the total distance between the points `totalDistanceBwPoints`. It then calculates the new coordinates of the propagated point.

I've tested this function, and it works perfectly for my use case, providing almost 99% accurate results. Thanks to everyone for their interest and support!